# Is there any way to put global loading message while every pages postback in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, javascript

In entire SharePoint site i want to put **global loading message** while every page **postback**, if user navigate from one page to another page it shows loading message until another page loads.

is it posible in SharePoint 2013?

any help would be appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it is possible to put global loading message, for that you can create custom master page for publishing page as well as system master page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to work in an event that captures the unload, in a MasterPage script or Site UserCustomAction, or anywhere you want to add script to the Page.

```
<script>
  window.onunload = function() {
    console.info('We are going to another page');
  }
</script>
```

You might want to use `onbeforeunload`

Details:

http://javascript.info/[booktitle-raw]/load-and-unload-events